# MEAN stack best practice package.JSON file

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, package.json

Bit of a broad question but I'm making a MEAN stack application.
I want to have a folder structure in my project where I separate the front and backend in seperate folders.

What is considered better practice and why?

1. Put the package.json file in both the client and the server folder
2. Put the package.json file only in the root of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the front-end and back-end as separate applications, because that's what they really are. This means that each one of them should have their own package.json file where you list the dependencies of the application: in one case the front-end, in the other the back-end.